# Cambiar lenguaje a Español en Element UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo configurado Element  UI en Ingles, y deseo cambiarlo a Español

```
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en' // lang i18n

// set ElementUI lang to EN
Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })
```

Intenté lo que dice la documentación , pero no e tenido éxito , talvez por mi falta de experiencia en el tema, al realizarlo se regresa al lenguaje chino

```
import esLocale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/es'
  Vue.use(ElementUI, { esLocale })
```

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/i18n#internationalization

Espero me puedan dar alguna ayuda, para poder continuar.

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Basándonos en la documentación esto te debe de funcionar:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale })

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Remplazando la línea **#4** por `element-ui/lib/locale/lang/es`, pero habiendo antes incluido el lenguaje español dentro de los archivos.

Aquí lo encuentras: [Element UI Español](https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/umd/locale/es.js)

Comment: gracias por tu comentario , efectivamente estuve pensando de esa forma , pero como podría incluirlo? gracias!

Comment: Justo bajar el archivo y meterlo a la carpeta **element-ui/lib/locale/lang/**,

Comment: Si , revise y ya tenia todos los lenguajes cargados , y ya lo había intentado , mi error fue que cree otra variable diferente de 'locale' para ruta del lenguaje es, cree 'esLocale ' como puse en el código de mi pregunta , en fin el error era ese .

Comment: Si te sirvió esta respuesta, no te olvides de marcarla como válida